# Suggestions on how to get a consistent xpath for a dom element in javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have been testing multiple code snippets, npm packages, etc. trying to find a way to consistently get an xpath from a dom node.  The only solution I found that works consistently is by using the chrome dev tools and choosing copy -> copyFullXpath.

What I currently have is working reasonably well but it doesn't seem to work well for a tags.  I'm specifically trying to get data from the shopify admin.  I realize they have an api but I need something I can implement in a chrome extension.  Shopify frontend is implemented in React but I don't think it's related.  I'm currently using this with success other than shopify a tags: https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/f8cf7e9c918dcf67c58f5affc0fb3716b0660232/extension/content/firebug/lib/xpath.js

I see chrome dev tools is open source but I don't know enough to extract the xpath portion (DomPath.js).

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work well with `<a>` tag? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

After more debugging, I found that hovering over anchor tags was causing a div to be inserted several nodes up in the hierarchy.  It was, in fact, due to the site.  I decided when get the xpath from the element, to clone the current node and re-append it to it's parent so the event listeners would be removed.  This solved my issue.